# How to pass two parameters in the 'onSave ()' function in react-editext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editext.

When I have

```
onSave = (val) => {
  console.log (val)
}
```

in console.log I have an editable value. I am also trying to pass `id` to`onSave`.

```
`onSave = (val, todoId) => {
  console.log (val, todoId)
} `
```

but this doesn't work, the second value is`undefined`. How to pass two values?

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-btc2df

```
import EdiText from 'react-editext';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "delectus aut autem",
          "completed": false
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "delectus aut autem",
          "completed": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  onSave = (val, todoId) => {
    console.log(val, todoId)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return <EdiText
                  key={todo.id}
                  type="text"
                  value={todo.title}
                  onSave={() => this.onSave(todo.id)}
                />
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also implemented the save functionality in my demo. Please check it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working demo for you!
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uysp7u

Just update below code

```
onSave={(value) => this.onSave(value, todo.id)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to pass previous param:

```
onSave={val => this.onSave(val , todo.id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this;

```
onSave={(val) => {
  this.onSave(val, todo.id)
}}
```